# Codenameone Android build error

Tags: codenameone

Since the morning I try to build an android application, in the Builds part it shows only Android Build Error and when I click on ERROR LOG it shows a page not found error. Is there any problem with build server??

Answer (score 0):

This happens for older versions of the plugins that still send to the google cloud. We've tried to track it down but it failed badly and since we're [killing off support to these old plugins](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ending-support-for-legacy-cloud.html) anyway the right solution is probably to just move forward.

This build still works your error URL is just broken and looks like: `https://cloud.codenameone.comhttps//codename-one.appspot.com/getData?...`

You can see the actual error by fixing the URL to remove the prefix and add the missing `:`:
`https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?...`

I'm guessing the error is due to downgrading to a free account or something similar. This happens because of the migration process to the new server once you follow these steps this problem should resolve itself.

Also starting this weekend builds sent using the old plugin or an old project will fail. You will need to update the plugin to 4.3 (or 4.0.3 in NetBeans) or newer. This is an important phase in removing App Engine from our build stack and moving to a new system.

If you are experiencing problems with a project do the following:

- Right Click the project
- Select `Codename One` → `Codename One Settings` or `Codename One Preferences`
- Click `Basic`
- Click `Update Project Libs` in the bottom left side